Android: Junit test to check/validate file inside Assets folder throw FileNotFoundException
I have abc.json file inside Assets folder of the Android project.
Everything is working in the application. i.e, able to read this file when launching the app on the phone.
Junit test to validate the file is not working.
@Test(expected = FileNotFoundException::class)
fun populateAbcFromAssets_input_empty_expected_FileNotFoundException() {
    
    val abcManager = AbcManager()
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()

    abcManager.populateAbcFromAssets(context, "")
}

@Test(expected = Exception::class)
fun populateAbcFromAssets_input_InvalidJSON_expected_Exception() {

    val abcManager = AbcManager()
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()

    abcManager.populateAbcFromAssets(context, "abc.json")
}

implementation of populateAbcFromAssets inside AbcManager class:
fun populateAbcFromAssets(context: Context, fileName: String) {
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null
    try {
        inputStream = context.assets.open("abc.json")
        val size: Int = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        val json = String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
        val gson = Gson()
        abcList = gson.fromJson(json, Array<AbcDataClass>::class.java)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        inputStream?.close()
    }
}

Both the test cases are throwing errors:
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:34)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)

---
---

at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:446)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2594)


double check the location of your assets folder.  Unrelated but I'm surprised your test didnt throw an error complaining about not being able to recognize Context as it is not part of junit.

As I mentioned, able to read the file in the app. This means there is no problem in reading the file, file name, etc...
the exception is throwing when running the test cases...

your error is saying you expect a FileNotFoundException but one is not being thrown.  if abc.json is being populated after you run this test that indicates your code is not throwing an exception and your test contains a logic error.
